# Excel AVERAGEIFS with OR

Tags: excel

Currently have an AVERAGEIFS formula where:

```
Col A is Arrival to Last Lab Results (POC Glu, POC INR) with the data being numbers
Col B is Activation Type in this case being "EMS (pre-hospital)"
Col C is poc_inr not needed which is either "Yes" or "No"
The formula is applied for a date range of 1 month.
```

The formula is pasted below:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(MM[Arrival to Last Lab Results (POC Glu, POC INR)], MM[Arrival Date/Time],">="&A30,MM[Arrival Date/Time],"<="&B30,MM[Activation Type],"EMS (pre-hospital)", MM[poc_inr not needed], "Yes")
```

Currently, the formula is only looking at cases where `[poc_inr not needed]` is a `"Yes."`I wanted a way to incorporate an OR statement where if the `[poc_inr not needed]` was a `"Yes"`, then the formula would continue to take the values in Col A but if `[poc_inr not needed]`was a `"No"` the formula would instead take a look at the values in another column altogether (let's name it Col D for simplicity's sake) and provide me the average of all the numerical values taken from Col A and Col D. All the other criteria and criteria range stay as is.

I have heard that AVERAGEIFS does not allow for OR functions, so I was wondering if anyone had a solution/alternative way of approaching this?

Comment: @QHarr Please clarify that statement with a very small example. It would seem incorrect to me. For example, if A1:A3 contains "A" and A4:A5 contains "B", whilst B1:B5 contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then the average of B1:B5 for the case that A1:A5 is EITHER "A" or "B" is 3. How would you obtain this result using the sum of 2 AVERAGEIFS, as you state?

Comment: I think a small, mocked-up example with expected results would be of benefit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `OR`, specify different criteria for each case and just add them together.  You will be better off using `SUMPRODUCT` and named ranges/tables to make your formula easier to read:

[image]

You should be able to adjust it without many problems:

```
 =(SUMPRODUCT((Table1[poc_inr]="Yes")*(Table1[Arrival]>=G2)*(Table1[Arrival]<=H2)*Table1[Last Lab Results])+SUMPRODUCT((Table1[poc_inr]="No")*(Table1[Arrival]>=G2)*(Table1[Arrival]<=H2)*Table1[Other result]))
 /(SUMPRODUCT((Table1[poc_inr]="Yes")*(Table1[Arrival]>=G2)*(Table1[Arrival]<=H2))+SUMPRODUCT((Table1[poc_inr]="No")*(Table1[Arrival]>=G2)*(Table1[Arrival]<=H2)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up using a combination of SUMIFS and COUNTIFS, but your answer helped me think in the right direction

Comment: Glad you liked, my pleasure.